# Needing help trying to pick up items with TypeError in text based game

Tags: python

```
#Trevor Anderson

# this dictionary connects each room to their destination by direction
rooms = {

        'Orderly Room': {'North': 'Admin Office', 'East': 'Recruiters Office', 'South': 'Supply Room', 'West': 'Drill Hall'},
        'Admin Office': {'East': 'First Sergeant Office', 'South': 'Orderly Room', 'Item': 'Grip'},
        'First Sergeant Office': {'West': 'Admin Office', 'Item': 'Magazine'},
        'Recruiters Office': {'South': 'Outside of the Armory', 'West': 'Orderly Room', 'Item': 'Ammunition'},
        'Outside of the Armory': {'North': 'Recruiters Office', 'Item': 'Terrorists'},
        'Drill Hall': {'North': 'Kitchen', 'East': 'Orderly Room', 'Item': 'Bolt'},
        'Kitchen': {'South': 'Drill Hall', 'West': 'Pantry', 'Item': 'Charging Handle'},
        'Pantry': {'East': 'Kitchen', 'Item': 'Crayons'},
        'Supply Room': {'North': 'Orderly Room', 'West': 'Cold Storage', 'Item': 'Receiver'},
        'Cold Storage': {'East': 'Supply Room', 'West': 'Weapons Room', 'Item': 'Trigger'},
        'Weapons Room': {'East': 'Cold Storage', 'Item': 'Stock'}

}

startGame = True
inventory = ()

# allows soldier to move room to room
def move(soldier, direction):
    global rooms
    startRoom = soldier

    # verifies there is a room in that direction
    if direction in rooms[startRoom]:
        startRoom = rooms[startRoom][direction]

    # tells soldier there is no room in that direction
    else:
        print('You can not go that direction')
        return soldier

    # returns where soldier is located
    return startRoom

# announces the rules and commands of the game
def gameRules():

    print('Move commands: go North, go East, go West, go South\nCollect all 8 items to win the game, or be captured by the terrorists!\nType exit if you want to exit the game ')

def pickupItem(startRoom):
    if 'Item' in startRoom:
        print('You have spot a', startRoom['Item'])


def show_status(startRoom):
    print(startRoom)
    print(inventory)

def game(item):

    if 'item' in inventory:
        print("you already have got this")
        print(" ".join(inventory))
    else:
        print('You have accounted for', 'Item')
        inventory.append(Item)
        print(" ".join(inventory))

def main():

    gameRules()
    soldier = ('Orderly Room')

    while startGame:

        startRoom = soldier

        pickupItem(rooms[startRoom])
        # output
        print('\nYou are in the', startRoom)
        print('Inventory:', inventory)
        print(pickupItem(startRoom))


        # villian is located
        if soldier == 'Outside of the Armory':
            print('Oh no! You have been captured!\nThanks for playing the game. Good luck next time!')
            break

        # separation between commands and input
        print('---------------------')
        soldier_move = input('Enter your move:\n')

        # invalid move syntax
        if 'go' in soldier_move or 'exit' in soldier_move:

            # split string
            command = soldier_move.split(' ')

            # move soldier
            if command[0] == 'go':
                soldier = move(soldier, command[1])

            # exit the gamego
            elif command[0] == 'Escape!':
                if len(inventory) == 8:
                    print('Equip your M4 rifle! Lets get out of here!')
                else:
                    print('You are missing some items!')

              # end loop with invalid command
            else:
                print('Invalid Command!')

        elif 'pickup' in soldier_move:
            command = soldier_move.split(' ')
            pickupItem(startRoom, command[1])

        # end loop with invalid command with continue to play
        else:
            print('Invalid Command!')
            continue


# run program
main()
```

Comment: You may want to fix your code formatting

Comment: Im in an intro online class and am super confused with it. Im not sure how to fix the code format to work

Comment: When posting code ensure you either indent the whole code block with 4 spaces (which is what `{}` button does) or use 3 backticks as opening code block marker and same for closing.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy mine shows like that on python but when I try to grab an item I'm getting this error code TypeError: pickupItem() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Right, that is the correct Error for your code. `pickupItem` takes one argument, but you are passing it two. Just don't do that.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy yeah I have no clue how I have 2 arguments... I am new to this and just trying to pass this class :(

Comment: `pickupItem(startRoom, command[1])` 2 args but,  `def pickupItem(startRoom)` 1 arg